# How can i test graph api before upgrade?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I got an email from Facebook. It says; "Your App,, is currently accessing Graph API v2.3 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime on 10 July, 2017. We estimate 6 endpoints that calls will be impacted by this change and may stop working after the automatic upgrade push. To ensure a smooth transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API v2.4 or higher. Use the API Upgrade Tool to understand exactly how this change will impact your app.

Note: If you do not see any impacted calls in the API Upgrade Tool, your app/code may not be affected by this upgrade.

Visit our changelog to see the full list of changes in all Graph API versions."

I couldnt understand something clearly. **How can i test my changes before upgrade?** **How can i test app with that changes?** I should test cause' its big app so users shouldnt affect.

Comment: check out the changelog to find out how to test calls with a higher version of the graph api. you just need to add a version tag.

Comment: @luschn I know i can test calls. Can i test app with higher version?

Comment: yes, as i said, just add the version tag as you can read in the changelog. only lower versions are not possible.

Comment: @luschn is it setVersion() tag in GraphRequest object? I did it for share post button and it works. Thank you!